# Entity Framework - Update/add value to existing value

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In Entity Framework is it possible to add a value to existing value in the database?
Currently I have this:

```
var ent = this.repository.GetSingle(id);
var moreQuantity = 5; // This is calculated in application logic
ent.quantity = ent.quantity + moreQuantity;
this.repository.SaveChanges();
```

It is possible to do the same in a single database interaction? I mean something like this in SQL:

```
UPDATE table SET quantity = quantity + {moreQuantity} WHERE id = {id}
```

Without using ExecuteSqlCommand or ExecuteStoreQuery.

The reason I am asking this is because there is a significant amount of time between the GetSingle and SaveChanges in my application, so I run with some concurrency problems. I manage to solve it with RowVersion and ConcurrencyCheck but I was looking for a better implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of EF are you using?

Comment: @MikeMazmanyan Hi, 6.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice library [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended)

Install it and write:

`context.repository.Update(e => e.id == id, e2 => new entity { quantity = e2.quantity + moreQuantity });`

Answer (score 1):

Current version of EntityFramework Extended (6.1) has deprecated the overload indicated in the accepted answer. The filtering and the actual update should be separated now. This is a good thing, since filtering can be easily dynamically constructed.

For the actual question, the query should like the following:

```
context.repository
    .Where(e => e.id == id)
    .Update(e2 => new entity { quantity = e2.quantity + moreQuantity });
```